# Java Converting PostScript to any image format

Tags: java, image, jpeg, postscript

I am currently in the process of writing an application in Java that creates PostScript documents and I am looking for a way to create a sample image of the document. The sample image is just to be used for the user to see how the document they are building looks in its current state.

Does anybody know of a way to do this? If anybody knows of an algorithm to do so that would be great. I'm also open to third party software if I have to (last resort).

Comment: rendering a PostScript file is an extremely complex task so you're not after an "algorithm".  Heck, PostScript is Turing-complete ; )   So your best bet would be a 3rd party Java API or a wrapper around an already existing program.  Which platform are you on and is it all happening on the server side or is it for a desktop app?  I'm using *ps2pdf* all the time and there are also commands allowing to render PostScript pages as bitmaps.

Comment: I want the final product to be cross-platform. Currently I'm developing in Windows 7.  So a 3rd Party API or wrapper sounds like a good way to go. I just need to find one. Any ideas?

Comment: Since your application creates the document, you might be able to write code to render it (either from the PostScript or from whatever data you build it from). Can you post an example PostScript document?

Comment: %!PS-Adobe-3.0
/Arial findfont
10 scalefont
setfont
500 500 moveto
(randomtext) show

Comment: I suppose the other option is to interpret the Postscript file and draw it to the screen using Java graphics. However, this may turn into quite a large project :)

Comment: Use Ghostscript. You will have to write a Java wrapper yourself but its the only open source cross-platform PostScript interpreter I know of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with Ghost4J like this :

```
// load PS document
PSDocument document = new PSDocument();
document.load(new File("input.ps"));

// create renderer
SimpleRenderer renderer = new SimpleRenderer();

// set resolution (in DPI)
renderer.setResolution(300);

// render
List<Image> images = renderer.render(document);
```

It works as well with PDF files. Checkout a full example [here](https://raw.github.com/zippy1978/ghost4j/master/src/main/java/org/ghost4j/example/SimpleRendererExample.java).

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned, the [PostScript language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript) is a Turing-complete programming langauge with a complex imaging model. Rendering the image drawn by an arbitrary PostScript language fragment is a huge task. You should definitely call a mature existing PostScript interpreter instead of trying to implement an "algorithm" to do so.

One well-regarded PostScript interpreter is [GhostScript](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/).  Ghostscript is free for non-commercial use. [Ghost4J](http://ghost4j.sourceforge.net/) appears to be a Java class framework which wraps the GhostScript API. (I have not used it.)

Or you could write the PostScript language code to a disk file, and invoke a separate process to render the code to an image file, and read the image file back from disk.  Check out [Stackoverflow Questions tagged "ghostscript"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ghostscript) for more ideas.

If you want a PostScript interpreter for commercial use, one option is the [Distiller Service of LiveCycle ES](http://livedocs.adobe.com/livecycle/es/sdkHelp/programmer/sdkHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm). LiveCycle ES is almost certainly not the low-cost solution. You might also be able to bundle a copy of Adobe Acrobat Professional, which includes a PostScript interpreter called Distiller. Then invoke a separate process to render the PostScript language code using Distiller, as for GhostScript above.

Other companies apart from Adobe offer PostScript interpreters on commercial terms.